# Issue with CompletableFuture - does not wait for all URLs to be called

Tags: java, asynchronous, concurrency, completable-future

Regarding concurrent async calls, the problem i have is that, after consecutive runs, the code does not wait until both of calls are finished and with a response included. Sometimes is executing both, sometimes only one of the URLs

What i am looking to achieve is:

a) to make CompletableFutures to wait until all responses are received

b) to extract in a List all the responses of provided calls

c) to be able to categorize them by a key-value pair (ex: request1, request2, request3WithInvalidData etc) and after completion to iterate over the List and extract what response and data per each request (statusCode, body etc) and to further make assertions.

If anybody can help me, it would be highly appreciated ! I'm new to multithreading and it's hard to grasp. A little help and explanation of solution would help me a lot !

Thank you ! (below is my code)

```
class HelloWorld {

private static void concurrentCalls(List<String> paths) {
    var client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();

    List<HttpRequest> requests = paths.stream()
            .map(URI::create)
            .map(uri -> HttpRequest.newBuilder(uri).GET().timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(20)).build())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    List<String> llll = new ArrayList<>();

    CompletableFuture<?>[] responses = requests.stream()
            .map(request -> client.sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString())
                    .thenApply(HttpResponse::body)
                    .exceptionally(e -> "Error: " + e.getMessage())
                    .thenAccept(llll::add))
            .toArray(CompletableFuture<?>[]::new);

   
    CompletableFuture.allOf(responses).join();

    llll.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> listOfUrls = new ArrayList<>();
    listOfUrls.add("https://postman-echo.com/get?foo1=bar1&foo2=bar2");
    listOfUrls.add("https://postman-echo.com/response-headers?foo1=bar1&foo2=bar2");
    concurrentCalls(listOfUrls);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    CompletableFuture<?>[] responses = requests.stream()
            .map(request -> client.sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString())
                    .thenApply(HttpResponse::body)
                    .exceptionally(e -> "Error: " + e.getMessage())
                    .thenAccept(llll::add))
            .toArray(CompletableFuture<?>[]::new);
```

This block of code takes all of your `HttpRequest` objects, calls `sendAsync()` on them, and then gives each of them some tasks to do after completing their respective call. Those tasks are the `thenApply()`, `exceptionally()`, and `thenAccept()`.

The issue comes when you call these 2 lines.

```
CompletableFuture.allOf(responses).join();

llll.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

The `join()` does exactly what you would expect - block the thread and wait for all the requests to finish and receive their responses. More specifically, the `join()` will not let the code continue until each of the `HttpRequest` objects has at least reached the `client.sendAsync()` line.

However, that's exactly the problem - the code hasn't had a chance to ***go past*** `client.sendAsync`, which means that it may or may not have enough time to be added to your list `llll`. Remember, being added to that list is one of the tasks we gave each `HttpResponse` object, but depending on how things run, it may or may not be fast enough to add the response to `llll` before we print the contents of `llll`.

This is why your solution is inconsistent - you have a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Example). If you wish to avoid your race condition, you must use the `collect(Collectors.toList())` function to store all of your responses into `llll`, and then you must replace your `CompletableFurure.allOf().join()` with individual calls to `join()` as part of a `CompletionStage`. Here is an example.

```
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.URI;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class HelloWorld {

   private static void concurrentCalls(List<String> paths) {
      var client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
   
      List<HttpRequest> requests = paths.stream()
               .map(URI::create)
               .map(uri -> HttpRequest.newBuilder(uri).GET().timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(20)).build())
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
   
      List<CompletableFuture<HttpResponse<String>>> inProgressResponses = requests.stream()
               .map(request -> client.sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString()))
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
               
      List<String> completedResponses = inProgressResponses.stream()
            .map(response -> response
                  .thenApply(HttpResponse::body)
                  .exceptionally(e -> "Error: " + e.getMessage())
                  .join())
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            ;
      
      completedResponses.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
      
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      List<String> listOfUrls = new ArrayList<>();
      listOfUrls.add("https://postman-echo.com/get?foo1=bar1&foo2=bar2");
      listOfUrls.add("https://postman-echo.com/response-headers?foo1=bar1&foo2=bar2");
      concurrentCalls(listOfUrls);
   }

}
```